# Cannot connect to internet from USB dongles in elementary os loki

Tags: release-loki, networking, internet, usb

I used `elementary os freya` and did a fresh install to `elementary os loki` yesterday night. Now I'm unable to use `USB Modems` ( `usb dongles`) for connecting to the Internet. In `Freya` there was no trouble in connecting from `usb modems`. But in `loki` when `USB modem` was plugged, `create new connection` does not appear in the network menu, (the modem shows signals are availables through the LED bulb) I was able to create a new connection from `edit connections` as in the below image.[image] As depicted in the image above, mobile broadband is not shown under the Devices. So how to connect to Internet using `usb modems`?

Comment: I have the seame problem, but with built-in ericsson 5321 on lenovo thinkpad t440s.... I just installed eOS loki, i'm coming from debian jessie and it was working out the box...

Comment: I cannot connect to the internet using my USB dongle, I can see the device if I run lsusb, and I added the connection through the network manager for the mobile broadband, and when I get to the part to select the device, its greyed out and says any device so I continued with that setting and selected to automatically connect, but it still does not connect to the network after doing all that you have described above. Guys I am disappointed because something like this, for an OS, should just work out of the box, and yes its growing and in Beta, but I am hesitant to install this OS on anyones lap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a temporarily solution until a fix is released, First connect the `usb dongle` and wait till it get detected in `Disks`. Then move on to the `Settings->Network` navigate to the `Ethernet` under the devices in the left panel (as shown in the above screen-shot), then  press `Edit Connections` then `Add` select `mobile broadband` from the `hardware menu`. Then  go on by filling fields, Once the`Editing <yourConnectionName>` window appears, move on to the `General` tab and mark `Automatically connect to this network when available`. This will automatically connect the `usb dongle` when it is plugged in. This works fine and is a temporarily solution until a fix is being released as OS update.

Comment: Yes, thats how i also got my usb modem to function and its working real fine. But we would love this to be fixed soon.

Comment: Thanks, Its working but it doesn't show that I'm connected to any network even on wing panel or on the network manager. I had to install `modem-manager-gui` to view the status of the connection!

Comment: thanks for this answer